# hide URL from end user during proxyPass/reverseProxyPass

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have two servers that are on separate machines.  We have DNS'd these internally to our network to:

- dev.server.com
- prod.server.com

All of our applications are hosted on prod.server.com, but my team wrote a new application in a version of a language that is not yet available on prod.  In order to allow users to use it, I'd like to keep users on the prod environment, with a link to this new application - but from the user's perspective, I don't want them to see themselves being redirected to dev.server.com, I want their address bar to stay the same as they're used to.  When they click the link to go to `prod.server.com/new_application`, I want their address bar to say `prod.server.com/new_application`, but I want it to **load** `dev.server.com/new_application`

After reading for several hours, it seems the **exact** way to do this is through a ProxyPass and a ReverseProxyPass.

In my apache, I made sure these two modules were being loaded:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Then, further on, I do the following:

```
<Proxy *>
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Proxy>

#### Proxy Stuff
#ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /new_application/ http://dev.server.com/new_application/
ProxyPassReverse /new_application/ http://dev.server.com/new_application/
```

When I click the `<a href="/new_application/">Click here</a>` that is hosted at `prod.server.com`, the page at `dev.server.com/new_application` loads - so half of my problem is working correctly - but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this hide itself from the user and keep `prod.server.com/new_application` what they see in their address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
    ProxyPassReverse /new_application/ http://prod.server.com/new_application/

But note that this only 'adjusts' the URL in the http header part of the conversation.  It doesn't fix any "full" urls in the content delivered from 'prod'.
(Edit) See `https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html` if you need to do more elaborate editing of links in content.

You don't need the
`<Proxy *> ... </Proxy>`
block - in fact, you probably don't want it ... that is to enable forward-proxy.
Use `ProxyRequests Off` to protect your server from use as a forward proxy.

It's a pretty dense read, but
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html
should help.